# C#/QML types convertion (double/real/float)

Tags: c#, floating-point, double, qml, type-conversion

my C# project is reading some configurations from a QML file.

The thing is that i'm not sure about some convertions...

```
QML        C#
int    <-> int
string <-> string
bool   <-> bool
```

are OK

I'm not sure about real/double in QML (to float/double in C#)
I looked for some info about precisions but didn't find anything very clear.

Does double in QML is equivalent to double in C# ?
Does real in QML is equivalent to float in C# ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# spec says :

> C# supports two floating point types: float and double. The float and double types are represented using the 32-bit single-precision and 64-bit double-precision IEEE 754 formats

So the only difference between float and double is the precision in C#.

[The QML reference says for Double](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qml-real.html):

> A double number has a decimal point and is stored in **double precision**, IEEE floating point format.

[and for the real](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qml-real.html)

> In QML all reals are stored in single precision, IEEE floating point
>   format.

They respect each other the IEEE 754 standard.
So the only difference between real and double in QML is the precision too.

According to [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_formats), it could be a good idea to parse C# float type as a real QML type and parse C# double type to double in QML.

Comment: It seems that this has changed `Note: In QML all reals are stored in *double* precision, IEEE floating point format` http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-real.html